# C# how to add values in ItemFields inside EmbeddedSchemaField of a STUB component

Tags: c#, sdl, tridion

I have an embedded schema for a STUB component metadata field which has 4 fields and marked as "Allow Multiple Values", along-with other fields in SDL Tridion. I am using SDL Tridion Web 9.0.

The STUB component metadata is blank initially. I am using a save event handler in SDL Tridion to populate this metadata from External Metadata of ECL component. I am using `EmbeddedSchemaField` to hold initial metadata field for the embedded field, but I am unable to populate the `ItemFields` inside the `EmbeddedSchemaField` while saving. I am using the following code to initially hold blank field from collection of metadata Fields of my component.

```
_images = ((EmbeddedSchemaField)metadataFields["Images"]);
```

where `metadataFields` is the metadata fields collection.

While trying to add values to the `ItemFields` inside, I am trying to use

```
IList<ItemFields> _imagesFields = _images.Values;
```

but it gives me Count = 0. So I am unable to do anything with this any further. Any suggestions/hints will be very very appreciated.

Comment: You might want to post this to https://tridion.stackexchange.com/

Comment: done @Shahid Eqamuddin